# Codeigniter active record return single array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

im returning data back from my db using codeigniter's database class , is there anyway I can put it into the same array without having to do additional array_merge logic after the loop completes?

```
foreach ($saved_forms[0] as $key => $value) {
     $this->db->select('form_text');
     $this->db->from('form_labels');
     $this->db->where('form_label', $key );
     $query = $this->db->get();

       $form_names  = $query->result_array();
       $form_titles[] = $form_names;

    }
```

### result array

```
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [form_text] => Participant Name
            )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [form_text] => Date of Birth
            )

    )
```

What i want :

```
 [0] => Array
       (
        [form_text] => Participant Name
        [form_text] => Date of Birth
       )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->select('form_text')
         ->from('form_labels');
         ->where_in('form_label', array_keys($saved_forms[0]));
         ->get();

foreach( $query->result as $label){
   $form_titles[] = $label->form_text;
}
```

It will produce a single array with the texts

Comment: can you comment on if this is faster then me doing  `array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });` ?

Comment: @Undermine2k Honestly I'm not sure, maybe you'll be interested in this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php#112722, if it was me though I would use the foreach because it's simpler

Answer (score 2):

When Running PHP 5 >= 5.5.0 you can achieve this with the built-in function [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$form_names = $query->result_array();
$my_array = array_column($form_names, 'form_text');
```

Produces:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Participant Name 
 [1] => Date of Birth 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$form_titles[] = $form_names;` with `$form_titles[] = $form_names["form_text"];`

Answer (score 1):

Simple use the `where_in()` use foreach to get all the keys and run your query in a go and get rid of running query again and again

```
$keys=array();
foreach ($saved_forms[0] as $key => $value) {         
    $keys[] = $key;    
}

$this->db->select('form_text');
$this->db->from('form_labels');    
$this->db->where_in('form_label', $keys); 
// or $this->db->or_where_in();   
$query = $this->db->get();
$form_names  = $query->result_array();
```

Comment: this removes the outer array layer but still gives me an extra level I don't need:
`(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [form_text] => Participant Name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [form_text] => Date of Birth
        )`